# Deploying ArcGIS Web App via windows IIS, domain instead of IP address

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-platform, web

So first off, I'm a newbie at web apps. I have put together a working ArcGIS web app that is hosted on an Amazon EC2 Windows Server 2012 via IIS. The web app is working great, but I can only access it via the IP address of the windows server "`http://<ip address>/ParkLocator`". I want to use a regular domain name to look more professional `http://www.<domain name>/ParkLocator`.

My first thought was that I needed to register a domain name so I acquired a domain name via GoDaddy. I thought I could just 'forward and mask' the domain name to forward traffic to the windows server. That worked, but now the web app is no longer mobile responsive, it only works right though the desktop.

Any advice?

Comment: Have you opened up a network debugger/developer tool(s) to see if all resources are being retrieved when you hit the application? Usually F12 in a browser like Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: you need to edit your site bindings see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v7HsUfry5Ks&feature=youtu.be&t=4m40s

Comment: Thanks guys, the instructions in the youtube video was the ticket! First the bindings, then there was a follow up video by the same guy with the next step, which was setting up websites with windows IIS and GoDaddy domains.